# building a C# asynchronous TCP proxy server

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy, asyncsocket

I am attempting to build a simple C# TCP proxy for my business so I can block certain websites from my employees.  All is well except I am having trouble seeing what website the user is trying to visit... I can see that the user has connected to my proxy server so I know I am getting connections but the OnRecieve callback isn't even firing.  Am I reading from the socket wrong?

Here is my code:

```
internal class AsyncState
{
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[AsyncState.BufferSize];
    public Socket Socket;
    public StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();
}

private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress[] addressCollection = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in addressCollection)
    {
        if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8080);
            Console.WriteLine("Local IP address found... " + localEndPoint.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }

    isListening = true;

    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(10);

            while (isListening)
            {
                resetEvent.Reset();

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for clients...");
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), serverSocket);

                resetEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }));

        thread.Start();
    }
}

private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
{
    resetEvent.Set();

    Socket clientSocket = (result.AsyncState as Socket).EndAccept(result);
    Console.WriteLine("Client has connected... " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

    AsyncState state = new AsyncState();
    state.Socket = clientSocket;
    state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, AsyncState.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), state);
}

private void OnRecieve(IAsyncResult result)
{
    AsyncState state = result.AsyncState as AsyncState;

    int totalRead = state.Socket.EndReceive(result);
    if (totalRead > 0)
    {
        state.Content.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, totalRead));
        state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, AsyncState.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), state);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state.Content.Length > 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Message recieved from client... " + state.Content.ToString());

        state.Socket.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost feel obliged not to answer, for the sake of your employees. Bros before bosses!

Comment: I up voted you just because I understand your feelings bra ;) But unfortunately this is the real world and some of my employees enjoy porn sites away from their homes haha

Comment: Nothing wrong with a little pr0n ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building a well working proxy is no simple task as you will have to understand and handle HTTP etc. in both directions...

I would recommend to either use an existing library for that OR some configurable proxy...

- http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/ (with source)
- http://sourceforge.net/p/portfusion/home/PortFusion/ (with source)
- http://www.wingate.com/
- http://www.squid-cache.org/

REMARK:

I don't know in which jurisdiction you are but using such technology without knowledge/consent of employees can in some places be a problem...

Another point: Instead of using such methods I would tell the employee to stop abusing the internet connection of the company 1-3 times and if that doesn't work I would rather fire that person... such employees is not only abusing the internet connection of the company but in worstcase is putting the company at risk (virus/trojan etc.) and also defrauding the company (if he does this in work hours)...

Comment: I have a well versed understanding of HTTP requests and their status (I design web applications).  I just need to know how to capture the request or HEAD of the request so I can see the status, user agent, etc and figure out what website they are trying to view before I send a response back to their browser

Comment: Again we have had every employee sign an internet usage agreement and I don't expect them to continue but for other purposes such as security and just for my own knowledge and curiosity I would still like to learn HOW to do this.  Knowledge is power and I simply love programming :)

Comment: @CrisMcLaughlin I can understand that (love to program + knowledge is power)... nothing better to learn from than source code of some well working piece of software in this case... esp. the 2nd link is rather helpful for your case

Comment: This answer is good because it does help solve the OP's stated problem... but it's great because it addresses the root problem: employees who can't be trusted.